# Sorting matrix based on aggregation in ssrs 2008

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a matrix in ssrs 2008 like below:

```
Reason #ofCancellations
[Reason] Count(Fields!CancelID.value)
```

It is working well. What I want is to sort this matrix based on the count columns in descending order. Normally, I was doing it by going Tablix propertoes -> Sorting. This time it does not let me write Count(Fields!CancelID.value) there, giving me error like Aggregations are not permitted while sorting a matrix. I prefer to do the sorting on the ssrs. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there Row and Column Groups? It looks like this is a simple tablix not a matrix.

Comment: yes, there is a row group (grouped by reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the sorting in your Row Group. Go to Row Group pane and right click the group Reason.

[image]

Select Group properties... and go to Sorting tab. Add a new sorting by expression and select A-Z for ascending or Z-A for descending.

```
=Count(Fields!CancelID.value)
```

Let me know if this helps.